# Can't install cargo-binutils library: Failed to find tool. Is `gcc.exe` installed?

Tags: windows, gcc, rust, rust-cargo, cc

When I run `cargo install cargo-binutils`, I get the below error. I have gcc installed and in my path, to the point where `where gcc` correctly returns the location.

**gcc version:** gcc.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

I couldn't find a solution to work, including the explanation in the link listed in the error. I'm on Windows 10.

```
error: failed to run custom build command for \`backtrace-sys v0.1.37`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: \`C:\Users\blahblah\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installEvEWRS\release\build\backtrace-sys-075604757ab74d2a\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
--- stdout
cargo:rustc-cfg=rbt
TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CC = None
CC = None
CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
DEBUG = Some("false")
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
running: "gcc.exe" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-m64" "-I" "src/libbacktrace" "-I" "C:\\Users\\BRENDA~1.BUR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installEvEWRS\\release\\build\\backtra
ce-sys-1e77a4d4c3ba2eda\\out" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTED=1" "-DBACKTRACE_USES_MALLOC=1" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTS_THREADS=0" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTS_DATA=0" "-DHAVE_DL_ITERATE_PHDR=
1" "-D_GNU_SOURCE=1" "-D_LARGE_FILES=1" "-Dbacktrace_full=__rbt_backtrace_full" "-Dbacktrace_dwarf_add=__rbt_backtrace_dwarf_add" "-Dbacktrace_initialize=__rbt_backtrace_initialize" "-Dbacktrac
e_pcinfo=__rbt_backtrace_pcinfo" "-Dbacktrace_syminfo=__rbt_backtrace_syminfo" "-Dbacktrace_get_view=__rbt_backtrace_get_view" "-Dbacktrace_release_view=__rbt_backtrace_release_view" "-Dbacktra
ce_alloc=__rbt_backtrace_alloc" "-Dbacktrace_free=__rbt_backtrace_free" "-Dbacktrace_vector_finish=__rbt_backtrace_vector_finish" "-Dbacktrace_vector_grow=__rbt_backtrace_vector_grow" "-Dbacktr
ace_vector_release=__rbt_backtrace_vector_release" "-Dbacktrace_close=__rbt_backtrace_close" "-Dbacktrace_open=__rbt_backtrace_open" "-Dbacktrace_print=__rbt_backtrace_print" "-Dbacktrace_simpl
e=__rbt_backtrace_simple" "-Dbacktrace_qsort=__rbt_backtrace_qsort" "-Dbacktrace_create_state=__rbt_backtrace_create_state" "-Dbacktrace_uncompress_zdebug=__rbt_backtrace_uncompress_zdebug" "-D
macho_get_view=__rbt_macho_get_view" "-Dmacho_symbol_type_relevant=__rbt_macho_symbol_type_relevant" "-Dmacho_get_commands=__rbt_macho_get_commands" "-Dmacho_try_dsym=__rbt_macho_try_dsym" "-Dm
acho_try_dwarf=__rbt_macho_try_dwarf" "-Dmacho_get_addr_range=__rbt_macho_get_addr_range" "-Dmacho_get_uuid=__rbt_macho_get_uuid" "-Dmacho_add=__rbt_macho_add" "-Dmacho_add_symtab=__rbt_macho_a
dd_symtab" "-Dmacho_file_to_host_u64=__rbt_macho_file_to_host_u64" "-Dmacho_file_to_host_u32=__rbt_macho_file_to_host_u32" "-Dmacho_file_to_host_u16=__rbt_macho_file_to_host_u16" "-o" "C:\\User
s\\BRENDA~1.BUR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installEvEWRS\\release\\build\\backtrace-sys-1e77a4d4c3ba2eda\\out\\src/libbacktrace/alloc.o" "-c" "src/libbacktrace/alloc.c"

--- stderr


error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `gcc.exe` installed? (see https://github.com/alexcrichton/cc-rs#compile-time-requirements for help)
```

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well. In my case I got:

> failed to run custom build command for `zstd-sys v2.0.1+zstd.1.5.2`
>
> Caused by:   process didn't exit successfully:
> `C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\zero2prod\target\debug\build\zstd-sys-f37cc8bfd3eec6ac\build-script-build`
> (exit code: 1)
>
> error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `gcc.exe` installed? (see
> https://github.com/alexcrichton/cc-rs#compile-time-requirements for
> help)

I was able to solve it by following the steps on [installing the Visual C++ extension from the VS Code marketplace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

This is how I did it:

1. Go to MSYS2.org https://www.msys2.org/ (You will also see the installation steps on the site, in case this answer gets outdated).
2. Download and install `msys2-x86_64-20220603.exe` (or whichever version is current). The installation is pretty straightforward, just take a note on the installation path as you will need to add this to the environment PATH later on.
3. A new program called "MSYS2" should've been installed. Open it, and you'll see a terminal window in it. You will run ALL of the commands mentioned below in this terminal. If you close it, open it again.
4. Run:

```bash
pacman -Syu
```

This will update the packages and databases.

5. Run (Again - This step may not be needed, but is recommended by MSYS2 in case packages need an additional updates.)

```bash
pacman -Syu
```

6. Run:

```
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

You will now see a selection of all the packages. If you don't know which to choose, just press enter on your keyboard and you shall get all of them (that's what I ended up doing).

After that, gcc.exe will be installed the bin folder of `mingw64`. Therefore:

7. Add the`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` file path to your path environment variable (or Wherever you decided to install it).

In case you need assistance on adding to the path, [check out this link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

8. Remember to restart your CMD/Windows Terminal/Power Shell for the environment path to take place.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/alexcrichton/cc-rs#compile-time-requirements says:

> Windows platforms targeting MinGW (e.g. your target triple ends in `-gnu`)
>     require `cc` to be available in `PATH`. We recommend the
>     [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org) distribution, which is using the
>     [Win-builds](http://win-builds.org) installation system.
>     You may also acquire it via
>     [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io), as explained [here][msys2-help].  Make sure
>     to install the appropriate architecture corresponding to your installation of
>     rustc. GCC from older [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) project is compatible
>     only with 32-bit rust compiler.

Try creating a symlink or hardlink to GCC called `cc`, somewhere on your path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried both of those links and put them on my path (at separate times) and I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: @guy Do `where cc` and `cc --version` work properly?